# How to transfer access token from 1 javascript file to another on the same html page without giving the access to the user to read it?

Tags: javascript

I have a form of 6 fields in HTML and an `import` button which import a JSON file. The file contains 8 elements 6 of which are the part of the HTML form and the other 2 are some confidential information. Now as soon as I import the JSON file, the form gets auto filled using the JSON elements. I can change any of the field using the form. There is another button named `save` which saves the 6 fields from the form in a new JSON file. Now the problem is that **How to pass the 2 confidential fields from one JSON file to another without giving the user access to read them.** I have read about passing data using **Local storage/ Session storage** and **Cookies**. I think using local storage is not a good idea for this case but I am not sure about cookies. What should I do?

Comment: If the "confidential" fields are in the form then the user can already read them if they really wanted to, so I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: the file is being uploaded by the user so anyways those confidential are accessible by them. You can add two hidden fields in the form containing confidential data such that confidential data won't be visible on the UI.  But they can be accessed at the client-side using JS.

Comment: @Aplet123 I just want that the files do not get stored on the local storage.